# jquery else statement not working inside panel animation

Tags: jquery

i wanted to make a side panel in jquery where when you click a button, a content animates to open and when you click the button again, the content animates to close. but the if statement is not working here. My jquery is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('.sidepanel-content').css("width","0px")){
        $('.sidepanel-trigger').click(function(){
            $('.sidepanel-content').animate({width:"150px"});

        });
    }
    else{
        $('.sidepanel-trigger').click(function(){
            $('.sidepanel-content').animate({width:"0px"});

        });
    }       
});
```

this only is making the if statement work, not else, i can understand why. because the if-else is coming under document.ready.
html:

```
<div class="sidepanel">

    <div class="sidepanel-trigger"></div>
    <div class="sidepanel-content">some sidepanel content</div>

    </div>
```

css:

```
.sidepanel{ position: absolute; left: 0;}
    .sidepanel-content{ width: 0px; float: right; overflow: hidden;}
    .sidepanel-trigger{ float: right; width: 30px; height: 30px; background-color: #40cde0; border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;}
```

here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3KwAZ/

also, pls give a code similar to this one, so i am able to see where i need to get it right..also pls dont give the option of

```
if('.sidepanel-content').hasClass('hidden'){}
```

as i already have it working with this code, but i dont want to include class. thanks

Comment: Try evaluating `$('.sidepanel-content').css("width","0px")` in the console and see what it returns.

Answer (score 4):

You need to put the `if` inside the click handler. Also, `.css("width", "0px")` *sets* the CSS, it doesn't compare it. And you should use `$(this)` so you only toggle the specific element that was clicked on, not all the other elements with the same class.

```
$(function () {
    $('.sidepanel-trigger').click(function () {
        var content = $(this).next(".sidepanel-content");
        if (content.css("width") == "0px") {
            content.animate({
                width: "150px"
            });
        } else {
            content.animate({
                width: "0px"
            });
        }
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/3KwAZ/7/)

However, a better way to do this would be with jQuery's `{width: toggle}` feature. Change the CSS to:

```
.sidepanel-content {
    display: none;
    width: 150px;
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

and use this JS:

```
$(function () {
    $('.sidepanel-trigger').click(function () {
        var content = $(this).next(".sidepanel-content");
        content.animate({width: 'toggle'});
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/3KwAZ/12/)

Comment: +1 However, the `if` statement will not evaluate correctly using the `css` method because it actually returns the css value as a string `0px`...I'd change it to `if($(this).width() == 0){`

Answer (score 1):

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3KwAZ/10/)**

- Get the `if() else()` statement block inside the click event.
- Use a common click function.
- Correct if statement is `$(this).css("width") == "0px"`.
- Use `$(this)` wherever possible instead of calling the selector everytime.

---

```
 $(document).ready(function () {


     $('.sidepanel-trigger').click(function () {

         if ($(this).css("width") == "0px") {
             $(this).animate({
                 width: "150px"
             });
         } else {


             $(this).animate({
                 width: "0px"
             });


         }

     });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if else block should be inside the onClick function, since onClick function is the event that is triggered first.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var show = true;

$('.sidepanel-trigger').click(function(){
    if(show)
    {
        $('.sidepanel-content').animate({width:"150px"});
        show = false;
    }
    else
    {
        $('.sidepanel-content').animate({width:"0px"});
        show = true;

    }

});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

one more solution for this is

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

          $( ".sidepanel-trigger" ).on( "click", function() {
              if($('.sidepanel-content').width() == 150){
                  $('.sidepanel-content').animate({width:"0px"});
                 }
                 else{
                     $('.sidepanel-content').animate({width:"150px"});
                 }
                });
            });
```